# in $http. What is wrong with this code?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I made a function to do it. `getTemplate` it called

And I call it from `templateUrl` and I gives him the name of the state

I do not understand why it does not work for me,
Even it does not make me alert in errorCallback

And there are no errors in the console

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <base href="{!!  url() !!}/">
    <title>{{ $title }}</title>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
<script>

  var BASE_URL = $('base').attr('href');
  var menus = {!! $main_menu !!};

  var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.router','ngRoute']);

   app.directive('mainMenu', function(){
     return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: BASE_URL + 'assets/angularTemplates/main-menu.html',
      controller: function($scope){
          $scope.menus = window.menus;
          $scope.BASE_URL = window.BASE_URL;
        }
     }
   });


   var getTemplate = function(name){
      $http({
         method: 'GET',
         url: 'http://localhost/LaravelAngular/public/assets/angularTemplates/demo.html'
       }).then(function successCallback(response) {
           alert('yyyy');
         }, function errorCallback(response) {
           alert('nnnnn');
         });

     templates = {hfome : '<h1>Hi !! </h1>'};
     if ( name in templates){
       return templates[name]; 
     }
     alert(43)

   };


var t = 'http://localhost/LaravelAngular/public/assets/angularTemplates/demo.html';

   app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider,$routeProvider) {

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
      });
    $stateProvider
    .state('pages', {
        url: '/:page',
        template: function($stateParams){
          return getTemplate($stateParams.page);
        },
        controller: function($stateParams){
          alert($stateParams.page);
        }
    })


  });

</script>

</head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container">

      <main-menu></main-menu><!-- Main menu created by angular -->

      <a ui-sref="pages({ page: 'home' })">Home</a>

      <div ui-view></div>


      @yield('content')

    </div><!-- end of container -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do you see the template being requested at all?

Comment: at a guess, having ui-router and ng-route running doesn't feel like a good idea as they do the same thing, and may well be conflicting

Comment: Please provide the fully reproducible code. The current one does not load properly with pure Angular

Comment: There is a problem in `ngRoute`
When I take it, then part of the page is not loaded
Have tested it ..
Thank you for your comment

Comment: You need to use the `templateProvider` in your `$state` settings, and return a promise for the pemplate using [$templateFactory.fromConfig()](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.$templateFactory)

Comment: Also, read about [$templateCache](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$templateCache) and this tutorial http://www.scriptscoop.net/t/65244dc676a3/angularjs-angular-ui-router-templateprovider-never-called.html